# Change the macro part, let two outputs have the same value

Tags: c, macros

```
#define polyMacro(a, b) (a*a + 8*a + 3*a*b - b*b)

//change this part so it will get same value with polyFunc
//change this part so it will get same value with polyFunc
//change this part so it will get same value with polyFunc

int polyFunc(int a, int b) 
{
    return (a * a + 8 * a + 3 * a * b - b * b);
}

void part2(int x, int y) {
    int x_copy = x, y_copy = y;



    printf(" polyFunc(x, y) = %d \n polyMacro(x, y) = %d \n\n", polyFunc(--x, --y), polyMacro(--x_copy, --y_copy));//please change the macro so polyMacro will have the same value with polyFunc 
int main()
{
    int x = -7, y = 3;//give value

    printf("Part 2:\n\n");//print
    part2(x, y);

    while (1);  // needed to keep console open in VS
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you see when you run your program?

Comment: There’s a `}` missing from `part2()`; what else is missing?

Comment: Hi! Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your question is just a block of code; try including some explanation on what you tried, how, why, what the expected output is.... give the most detail you can to help others help you. Otherwise, no one will take the time needed to understand what you need.

Comment: Note [Why are these constructs using pre and post increment undefined behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior)

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your macro part like this :

```
 #define polyMacro(a, b) ({ typeof(a) a1= a;\
                    typeof(b) b1= b;\
                    a1*a1 + 8*a1 + 3*a1*b1 - b1*b1;\
                    })
```

By doing so, your macro increments or decrements the integer and saves it in a1 and b1 respectively. Operations are now done on a1 and b1.

Instead of:

```
--x_copy*--x_copy + 8*--x_copy + 3*--x_copy*--y_copy - --y_copy*--y_copy
```

you get

```
int a1= --x_copy;
int b1= --y_copy;
a1*a1 + 8*a1 + 3*a1*b1 - b1*b1;
```